# Outbound calls using freeswitch

Tags: freeswitch

This is my external sip_profile:

```
<gateway name="outbound">
  <param name="realm" value="10.0.1.5:5062"/>
  <param name="username" value="1001"/>
  <param name="password" value="1234"/>
  <param name="dtmf-type" value="rfc2833"/>
  <param name="expire-seconds" value="600"/>
  <param name="register" value="false"/>
  <param name="caller-id-in-from" value="false"/>
</gateway>
```

and my dialplan is as such:

```
<extension name="outbound_pstn">
  <condition field="destination_number" expression="^(.*)$">
    <action application="set" data="effective_caller_id_number=${outbound_caller_id_number}"/>
    <action application="bridge" data="sofia/gateway/outbound/$1"/>
  </condition>
</extension>
```

I am using the HT503 as my ATA. Freeswitch is running on the IP 10.0.1.5 and ATA is at 10.0.1.9

I can't seem to be able to make an outbound call. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

`realm` should be the address of the remote side, and in your example it's set to freeswitch'es local address

Answer (score 1):

If you want to connect Freeswitch to another PBX/switch you should set:

```
<param name="register" value="true"/>
```

for PSTN registration is not required. Use something like this:

```
<include>
  <gateway name="sipmarket">
    <param name="username" value="user1"/>
    <param name="realm" value="sipmarket.net"/>
    <param name="from-user" value="user1"/>
    <param name="from-domain" value="sipmarket.net"/>
    <param name="password" value="strong_password"/>
    <param name="expire-seconds" value="300"/>
    <param name="register" value="true"/>
    <param name="register-transport" value="udp"/>
  </gateway>
</include>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check out http://wiki.freeswitch.org/wiki/Main_Page and look for the outbound gateway pages. You don't have to define realm, unless you want to.

You need to have the gateway actually register to a SIP provider to make calls as well.

Comment: He says he's using an ATA, presumably to use a local PSTN line, so he doesn't actually need a SIP provider.

Comment: Also, he *has* to define realm. The only reason for not defining it would be if the gateway name already contained the remote server address. See https://wiki.freeswitch.org/wiki/Clarification:gateways

Answer (score 0):

If you digit

sofia status gateways

can you see your gateway "outbound"? Otherwise you have to digit:

sofia profile external rescan

if you put your gateways under external sip profile.